# How to check if a node already exists in neo4j database using neo4jrestclient

Tags: python, neo4j, neo4jrestclient

I have one node in my database called Admin where I'm putting some admin informations, the values of this node can be change later but it's not sure if it's created or not.

What I want is to check if it's already exist i'll modify the data else i'll addthe new one.

PS: I'm using neo4jrestclient with python 3

Answer (score 0):

You just need to [perform a Cypher query](https://neo4j-rest-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/queries.html?highlight=cypher) that uses the [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/clauses/merge/) clause.

The `MERGE` clause has `ON CREATE` and `ON MATCH` options if you want to set some values only when the node is created and/or matched, respectively.

Comment: I'm storing a mean value, so if the node doesn't exist I'll just add the first value because it has no mean, but if there is a mean calculated before i'll need to get the data make some calculations them store the new mean. So, I need to perfom some calculations between the two actions(check and add/modify).

Comment: This is the kind of detail that should be in your question. Are you saying that it is not possible to make the calculation within a `SET` clause (that appears right after the `ON CREATE` or  `ON MATCH`)? If so, you should show in your question the Cypher code that you already have, and explain clearly what you are trying to do.